# THREE.FontLoader() doesn't work in Three JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm new in Three JS and I would like to create a 3D text. I followed most of the tuto to create it, but I have an error even if I follow all the steps or copy/past the tuto's code.
This is my component :

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import bumped from "../Bumped.json";

const Text = () => {
  const font = new THREE.FontLoader().parse(bumped);

  const textOptions = {
    font,
    size: 5,
    height: 1,
  };

  return (
    <mesh>
      <textGeometry attach="geometry" args={["three.js", textOptions]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" />
    </mesh>
  );
};

export default Text;
```

My errors :
//THREE.FontLoader has been moved to /examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader.js

//Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).parse is not a function

Of course, this component will be inside a Canvas element in the main page.
My console Errors : [My console Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P80yX.png)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error means that `FontLoader` is not part of the core library anymore since `r133`. You need an additional import to use this loader in your application. Try it with:

```js
import { FontLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader.js';
```

Notice that you use `FontLoader` now without the `THREE` namespace.

Comment: thank you very much ! now the error left

Comment: Maybe you should replace 'jsm' to 'js' in the path if you use `require` syntax